# работа класса с другим классом(С++, ООП)

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Почему когда класс Apple находиться выше класса Human, то показывает ошибку, а когда класс Human i класс Apple поменять местами, то всё работает? Подскажите, пожалуйста, знатоки ООП;)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Apple;
class Human;


class Apple
{
public:
  Apple(int weight, string color)
  {
    this->weight = weight;
    this->color = color;
  }
  friend void Human::EatHalfApple(Apple& apple);
private:
  int weight;
  string color;
};

class Human
{
public:
  void EatHalfApple(Apple& apple);
};

void Human::EatHalfApple(Apple& apple)
{
  apple.weight /= 2;
  cout << apple.weight << endl;
}

int main()
{
  Apple apple(145, "RED");
  Human John;
  John.EatHalfApple(apple);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: К ООП это ни имеет никакого отношения, просто для использования `Human::что-то` это что-то должно сначала должно быть объявлено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что в классе `Apple` есть

```
friend void Human::EatHalfApple(Apple& apple);
```

Но к этому моменту компилятор знает только о том. что есть такой класс - `Human` - это вы ему объяснили... но вот что внутри него есть, в частности, есть ли метод `EatHalfApple` - ему неизвестно, проверить он этого не в состоянии - вот и сообщает об ошибке.

Если же поменять их местами - то

```
void EatHalfApple(Apple& apple);
```

ошибки не вызывает, так как компилятору известно, что такой класс - `Apple` - есть, а что внутри него или каков его размер - в этом объявлении неважно.

Comment: А как тогда сделать что б компилятор видел что в классе Human, до его инициализации при этом не меняя их местами?

Comment: А никак. Давать полное объявление класса первым. Или не ограничиваться одной дружественной функцией, а делать другом весь класс...

Comment: Или сделать функцию статической вне класса. И объявленную дружественной к обоим классам.